# Colored Icon Font in JavaFX

Tags: java, fonts, javafx

I have a JavaFX application in which I would like to use a few icons. Currently, I parse all text that might have an icon in it for a specific string a characters, for example ":icon:", and I build TextFlow in which I replace the matched keywords with an image. Then I just display the TextFlow as a graphic within the Label/TextField/etc. This feels very sloppy to me. Is there a better solution?

I would like to use a custom font which replaces a few unicode characters with the small number of icons I want to use, but it is essential that the icons have color in them. Is this something that can be done with a font? Can I use CSS to color specific characters of text? Am I on the right path here at all?

Comment: TextFlow is the right way to do it.  I'm not sure a TrueType font can render in multiple colors, but even if it can, generating such a font at runtime is going to be quite difficult.  As for your other question:  Text is a subclass of Shape, so it can have CSS applied to it, including [-fx-fill and -fx-stroke properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#shape).  Simply make a separate Text object for the run of differently colored characters.

Comment: In doing so though, I find that things like Tooltips, Labels, etc do not size well because they are being used with a graphic. Perhaps it is a flaw in my text flow builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wish to use a web font for this.

This sample uses the [Google Material design icons font](https://www.google.com/design/icons/).

[image: loveyou]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MixedTextAndIconFonts extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        Text i = new Text("I");
        Text love = new Text("\uE87D");
        Text u = new Text("you");
        i.setStyle("-fx-font-family: \'Indie Flower\'; -fx-font-size: 80; -fx-fill: forestgreen;");
        love.setStyle("-fx-font-family: \'Material Icons\'; -fx-font-size: 60; -fx-fill: firebrick;");
        u.setStyle("-fx-font-family: \'Indie Flower\'; -fx-font-size: 80; -fx-fill: forestgreen;");

        TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow(
                i,
                love,
                u
        );
        textFlow.setStyle("-fx-padding: 20px; -fx-background-color: azure;");

        Scene scene = new Scene(textFlow);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower");
        scene.getStylesheets().add("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

For a quick sample, I inline the styles, but for a "real" app, you would probably use an external CSS stylesheet and meaningful constant names for the unicode code points of the icon glyphs you wish to include.

*Further resources*

There are other similar resources available on the web if you search for them, such as [fontawesomefx](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx), [icon8 webfont conversion guide](https://icons8.com/2013/10/27/how-to-convert-icons-to-a-web-font/) and [icomoon.io](https://icomoon.io).

Comment: This looks really promising, I'll see what I can do with this!