# Cannot load font-face javafx

Tags: css, javafx, material-design, font-awesome, font-face

i have a little problem, i'm using Javafx and just put icon in a Text .
So i found this post which could help me : 
[Colored Icon Font in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33423549/colored-icon-font-in-javafx?answertab=active#tab-top)

The solution given by Derek is working but when i try to put my style in a css , it is not working:

```
@font-face {
  src: url(typeface/fontawesome-webfont.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower';
  src: url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower);
}

@font-face {
  src: url(typeface/govicons-webfont.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  src: url(typeface/fontawesome-webfont.ttf);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "MaterialIcons";
  src: url(typeface/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf);
}


#i {
  -fx-font-family: 'Indie Flower'; 
  -fx-font-size: 80; 
  -fx-fill: forestgreen;
}

#love {
  -fx-font-family: "MaterialIcons";
  -fx-font-size: 60;
  -fx-fill: firebrick;
}

#u {
  -fx-font-family: "Indie Flower";
  -fx-font-size: 80;
  -fx-fill: forestgreen;
}
```

And then this is my java class where i call everything  :

```
public class Test extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myProxy");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "myProxy");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "myPort");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "myPort");

    Text i = new Text("I");
    Text love = new Text("\uE87D");
    Text u = new Text("you");

    u.setId("u");
    i.setId("i");
    love.setId("love");
    i.getStyleClass().add("i");
    love.getStyleClass().add("love");
    u.getStyleClass().add("u");

    TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow(i, love, u);
    textFlow.setStyle("-fx-padding: 20px; -fx-background-color: azure;");

    Scene scene = new Scene(textFlow);
    final File externalCSSFile = new File("resources/Style.css");
    // Get style from external CSS
    scene.getStylesheets().add("file:///" + 
    externalCSSFile.getAbsolutePath().replace("\\", "/"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

of courses the files called exist with the correct path . 
So if you have any idea with it is not working , pls help me :)

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: the problem is that font face for the text and the icon isn't loading , i have a basic typeface for text and nothing for the icon ...